# Open setting from Application iOS9

Tags: ios, settings, ios9

I am trying to open setting from my app in a button action, I know the following code works but how can I do similar thing on iOS 9?

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"General&path=Network/VPN"]];
```

Or is there any other way to open setting page from app? 
If it is not possible can I open Wifi setting?

Found the solution:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=Safari"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this to open settings page from your app

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

Comment: thanks but it opens my app's setting, I want to go to setting main page.

Comment: It will open main settings page in device or simulator.

Comment: I'm trying that but it opens setting>myApp

Comment: You can only open your own apps settings. There is no way to open general settings